# Strapi not making new server (node v10.14.1)

Tags: node.js, strapi

i have problem with making new Strapi server.
**I am using node v10.14.1 and strapi 3.0.0-alpha.15**
When i go strapi new server i can selcet database (MongoDB), and than nothing...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the NodeJS version, one solution is to install **nvm**, with it you can manage multiple NodeJS versions, then install one of the NodeJS where the strapi new isn't bugged. I used **NodeJS v8.11.4** to initialized my Strapi then *after installation* return to the last version, it should works.

S.